# increase limit within a program

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I have a C program on Ubuntu. This program needs to open a lot of files. So I have to run it as the following:

```
ulimit -n 10000; ./xyz
```

Wonder if there is a way to do something within the program xyz itself to increase the limit. The program runs as root user, so it has the necessary privilege. In the C program (source code), I called

```
system("ulimit -n 10000");
```

But it doesn't work, which is not surprise.

Answer (score 1):

See [getrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html)

Consider using the `getrlimit(2)` and `setrlimit(2)` routines.  Note that only a process running with superuser privilege can increase a limit; any user can reduce their resource limits.

Comment: Thanks.   The perl module "BSD::Resource" allows user to set a few parameters, but don't anyone related the max number of file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

why not write a wrapper?

xyz_wrapper.sh

```
ulimit -n 10000; ./xyz
```

then simply run the wrapper

```
./xyz_wrapper.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the workaround I have been using. When I copy my perl program around, I have to copy the wrapper file, which is error-prone.